# Term for -ed as an adjectival suffix?

Tags: terminology, nouns, adjectives

By which I mean changing a noun into an adjective by adding '-ed'.
For example: the noun 'horn' becomes the adjective 'horned'

Is there a term for the type of adjective that is formed from a noun by adding '-ed'?

For comparison, when a verb becomes a noun by adding '-er' the noun becomes an 'agent noun' and the suffix is an 'agentive'

Comment: I'd go along with Miztli's answer: 'denominal adjective', the process being called 'adjectivalisation' (by affixation). I'd call a noun formed from a verb a 'deverbal noun', the process being called 'nominalisation'. As you say, the noun denotes a person filling the agent role with respect to the verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a name for this specific case that's more general than "denominal adjective" but it might be called a "possessive denominal adjective". There is work on this out there, e.g. [this abstract](http://www.cssp.cnrs.fr/cssp2011/abstracts/cssp2011DeoFrancezKoontzGarboden.pdf) (p.2) by Ashwini Deo, Itamar Francez and Andrew Koontz-Garboden.

Answer (score 1):

Compare *horned beasts* to *crowned heads*.

I'd call this a sort of indirect passive deverbal adjective . The *-ed* represents the past (passive) participle form of a verb which is represented by the same morpheme as the underlying noun. In effect, the noun *N* is recategorized as a verb, whether or not that verb is actually in current use, and its participle is employed in the passive sense "furnished with *N*".

I don't know a term for the thematic role here. Unless someone comes up with something better, I suggest *praebitive*, from *praebere*, "furnish, supply, provide".

Comment: I think this explanation is correct. "Horned" is the past participle of the verb "to horn", which is the deverbalisation of the noun "horn".